# Relative path to images in access reports

Tags: vba, image, ms-access, report, relative-path

It is my first time building a database and I wanted to share a solution to a problem I encountered.

My problem was that I wanted to show different images for each record in a report, but I also wanted to be able to move the database. This was a problem. I search in all the forums and all the different solutions didn’t work. I also found an article written by Microsoft saying that the only way is to either store the full path to the images or to store the image in the database. But this causes a problem if the database is moved, or storing the images in the database will take up a lot of storage space.

The problem is that the codes doesn’t work for each record in the report, the codes are for the entire report. So writing codes to find the backend and the image folder would result in displaying the first image in the report for all the records in that report.

However I discovered, when only storing the name of the image in a table, it would sometimes work (but it shouldn’t have, because I didn’t have the path) but when I restarted the database it would stop working. Investigating further I discovered that whenever you open the file browser it will store the path in some kind of memory. As long as the path to the images is stored in the memory it will be able to link the images to the path.

So my solution…

When the form, from where you access the reports is opened, the file browser is opened and the path to the images is pasted in (using codes to find backend and the image folder) and then the browser is closed. And this creates a link to the image names (stored in a table) with the path. And each different images will be shows for each different records in the report.

Not a pretty solution. Whenever the form is opened, you will see a flash of the file browser. But it gets the job done.

In the load form event:

`'    this will find the backend and the image folder:

```
Dim filepath As String
Dim strBackEndPath As String
Dim lenPath As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

strBackEndPath = CurrentDb.TableDefs("yourTabeInBackend").Connect
j = InStrRev(strBackEndPath, "=") + 1
strBackEndPath = Mid(strBackEndPath, j)
BackPath = Left(strBackEndPath, InStrRev(strBackEndPath, "\"))

filepath = BackPath & "YourImageFolder\"

'this will open the folder browser and paste in the path and close it:

Dim f As Object
Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
Dim varFile As Variant
Dim strPath As String
Dim fileName As String

With f
.InitialFileName = (filepath)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
SendKeys "{ESC}", True
f.Show

For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
Next varFile
End With
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You can move the pictures to a *subfolder* of the folder of your database.

Then save the pictures' names like this:

```
Picture1.jpg
Picture2.jpg
```

etc.

When you run the application, obtain the path to the pictures:

```
PictureFolder = CurrentProject.Path & "\FolderName\"
```

Then the path to a picture will be:

```
PictureFolder & Me!PictureFileName.Value
```

When you "move" your database, move both the database file and the folder with the picture files with it.

Comment: That will work for a form, or if you have one record in a report. But if you want to have different images for several records in a report it will not work (for me anyway). It will show the image for the first record in the report for all the records in the report.

Comment: Yes, you will need something more for a continuous form, but you sure get the idea. Create a helper function, that always returns the paths including the current folder like the `UrlContent` function [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html). Another option would be to store the pictures in a shared folder on network server.

Answer (score 1):

yup, i just encountered same problem and i agree with what Richard_Ha said, but in my case i solve it with storing image path on textbox and its work..

first textbox name "***fileimage_txt***" and bound to list of image filename on table

second textbox name "***image_path***" with property

```
Source Control : =GetImagePath()
visible : No (if u dont want it get printed)
```

and image control with property

```
Source Control : =[path_txt] & [fileimage_txt]
```